# tomcat 5 file upload getting zero size

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, http-headers, tomcat5.5

We have migrated our java application running Tomcat 5.0.28 on window 2012 on other server with same configuration (Same source code, same configuration & same Java version), but when application trying to save the file on other server using web service it saves zero file size.

we have enabled debug log,so we are getting only difference in http header size

Working environment log

```
08 02 2016 14:34:52 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
 DEBUG header - >> "POST /livelink-ws-euro/upload HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
08 02 2016 14:34:52  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.addHostRequestHeader(HttpMethodBase.java:1235)
DEBUG HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
08 02 2016 14:34:52 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
DEBUG header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1[\r][\n]"
08 02 2016 14:34:52 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
DEBUG header - >> "Host: uat1.livelink-euro.saint-gobain.com:801[\r][\n]"
08 02 2016 14:34:52 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
DEBUG header - >> "Content-Length: ***846823***[\r][\n]"
```

Non working environment log

```
 DEBUG header - >> "POST /livelink-ws-euro/upload HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
  08 02 2016 15:25:12 org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.addHostRequestHeader(HttpMethodBase.java:1235)
 DEBUG HttpMethodBase - Adding Host request header
08 02 2016 15:25:12 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
 DEBUG header - >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1[\r][\n]"
08 02 2016 15:25:12 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
 DEBUG header - >> "Host: uat1.livelink-euro.saint-gobain.com:801[\r][\n]"
08 02 2016 15:25:12 org.apache.commons.httpclient.Wire.wire(Wire.java:69)
 DEBUG header - >> "Content-Length: ***1030***[\r][\n]"
```

We checked all possible solution like Disable firewall side,disable antivirus,increase uploading timeout, locale setting but no success.

Comment: which api are you using to upload file?